# error using print on bash server for python script

Tags: python, unicode, callback, keras

I am not very familiar with shell or bash server.
I run a python script on a bash server using Keras on a classification problem.

```
! /bin/sh -p

python3 wrapper_DNN.py
```

I use a own callback functions which prints the performance at the end of each epoch. This leads to the following error:

```
...

File "/home/310122653/Git/DNN/Performance_callback.py", line 146, in on_epoch_end

**print** ("\u2014 train_accuracy: %f \u2014 val_f1: %f \u2014 val_precision: %f \u2014 val_recall: %f - _val_accuracy: %f"

%(_train_accuracy, _val_f1, _val_precision, _val_recall,
_val_accuracy)) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2014' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to tell ... ?the bash server? how to encode the ascii code (As I also run the code elsewhere I do not just want to switch off the printing)?

Directly a follow-up question, can I generally not print on a bash server (It does not have any way to view it anyway)? So, should I also use verbose mode 0 to not have any print output?

P.S. it's late here, so I might not respond immediately..

Comment: This is a Python issue, unrelated to Bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: But the error only appears on the  bash server...?

Comment: Please read the linked question and associated answers. It's a fairly common Python issue.

Comment: Try exporting `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF8` in the server before starting the Python process. Or set the locale to something using UTF-8.